# XCopy WPF deployment

Tags: wpf, deployment, pdb-files, xcopy

If I wanted to just xcopy my WPF app, what are the minimum necessary files from the Release folder to copy?

In my Release folder, I have various dlls that my project references, a vshost.exe, a vshost.exe.manifest, .pdb files, etc.  Is it necessary to copy all of those files to each machine I want to install my app to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an xcopy deployment, I take the...

executable

any dll's in the folder

the app.config, if there is one

I leave behind the manifest and anything with .vshost. in the name, and the pdb files.

NOTE:  There is a most excellent blog entry by John Robbins on PDB files and why sometimes it's a good idea to deploy them along side.  It's worth a close read [PDB Files](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx)

Comment: This is what worked in my case.  I was unable to embed the referenced dll's into the app so I had to copy them over as well.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum files you need are *.bin *.exe and app.config if you have one.